# How to format time in clocktable to HH:MM:SS

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using a clocktable that has an output format for the duration like below:

```
| Headline                                 | Time |
+------------------------------------------+------+
| *Total time*                             | 2:01 |
+------------------------------------------+------+
```

This is the format from `org-duration-format` and checked on how this can be changed. But could not find a way to reach a result that is similar to:

```
| Headline                                 | Time     |
+------------------------------------------+----------+
| *Total time*                             | 02:01:00 |
+------------------------------------------+----------+
```

The only format option are al without the leading zero for the hours. Anyone has a suggestion on how this time duration can be formatted in `HH:MM:SS`?

Comment: The hours field can become arbitrarily large: it does not necessarily fit into two digits, so having it zero-padded to two places is somewhat artificial. The only way I can see of changing it as you want is to change the code. You can try submitting an RFE to the Org mode mailing list, but I'm not sure whether it will be accepted.